# Is there any standard algorithm for doing pairwise comparison of Vector Elements?

Tags: c++, c++11

I basically have two vector with unordered elements who can be checked for only equality. Is there any standard algorithm like std::equal to do compare all n^2 pairs and check whether all the elements of one vector lies in the other?

Comment: Sort in O(nlogn) and compare in O(n)?

Comment: This could be a job for `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @DyP: *unordered elements that can only be checked for equality* sounds as *impossible to sort*.

Comment: @Jon It could be.  I wouldn't have thought that the unordered containers supported `==` and `!=`, but apparently they do.  The worst case complexity is O(n^2) (which is why I wouldn't have expected it to be supported), but in most cases, you probably won't have the worst case.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas So it sounds.  On the other hand, I don't think I've ever seen a data type for which it was impossible to define some sort of arbitrary ordering which was sufficient for `sort` (even if it doesn't correspond to any logical ordering).

Comment: @JamesKanze: The first thing that came to mind is `double` allowing for `NaN`, but then you can do bit magic to do the sorting through conversions to `uint64_t` and comparing bitwise. The order won't be the correct one, but it will be *some* ordering. Then again you cannot compare `NaN` through equality either...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas The first thing that came to my mind was complex.  Complex numbers do not have a defined order (and `std::complex` doesn't support '<' et al.), but it's easy to define an arbitrary order over them.

Comment: You can detect `NaN` and just sort it somewhere (`NaN` compares non-equal to itself).  In order to put data into an `unordered_set`, you'd need to hash it -- if you can hash it, you can probably sort it by just doing N uncorrelated hashes and sorting on them (with an exponentially vanishingly small probability of collision in N).  However, if you are hashing it, you might as well unordered set it.

Answer (score 4):

How big are the vectors?  Something like:

```
template <typename T>
bool
unorderedEqual( std::vector<T> const& v1, std::vector<T> const& v2 )
{
    return v1.size() == v2.size()
        && std::find_if(
            v1.begin(), v1.end(),
            [&v2]( T const& elem ) { 
                return std::find( v2.begin(), v2.end(), elem ) == v2.end();
            } ) == v1.end();
}
```

might do the trick, but it's O(n^2) (which means it's only good
for very small vectors), and it won't work if the vectors 
contain duplicate elements.  (Note too that I've not tested it,
so it probably contains typos and other errors.  But it should
be close enough to give the general idea.)

Otherwise, I think you'll have to sort; even if the objects
don't support less than, you should be able to define an
ordering function.  (The order can be arbitrary, with no
significance except to allow the use of `std::sort`.)

Comment: For duplicates, I guess you should be using `std::count` ? Still, it seems bothersome to actually *not* use a side data-structure (like a `std::unordered_map<T, size_t>` to keep count of the number of occurrences of each element).

Answer (score 2):

The least expensive way for *larger* vectors is most likely to sort both and then test for equality

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// ....

vector<yourType> v1;
vector<yourType> v2;

sort(v1);
sort(v2);
bool result = equal(begin(v1), end(v1), begin(v2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vector holds data, which is expensive to copy or swap:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

typedef std::vector<std::size_t> Index;
typedef std::vector<int> Data;
inline void init(Index& index, const Data& data) {

    struct Less
    {
        const Data& data;

        Less(const Data& data)
        :   data(data)
        {}

        bool operator () (std::size_t a, std::size_t b) {
            return data[a] < data[b];
        }
    };

    index.reserve(data.size());
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
        index.push_back(i);
    }
    Less less(data);
    std::sort(index.begin(), index.end(), less);
}

int main(){

    Data d0 { 1, 0, 4, 2, 5, 3 };
    Data d1 { 5, 2, 3, 0, 4, 1 };

    if(d0.size() == d1.size()) {
        Index i0;
        Index i1;
        init(i0, d0);
        init(i1, d1);
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < d0.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << d0[i0[i]] << " == " << d1[i1[i]] << std::endl;
            if(d0[i0[i]] != d1[i1[i]]) {
                std::cout << "Not equal" << std::endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Equal" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```